# Restricting Tomcat logging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging

Tomcat logges in eclipse everything starting with DEBUG. It doesn't log only its own properties but other stuff allow themselves to log (like:

`[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment` or
`[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` and many many others).

I want to limit tomcat logging to info or warning. I tried going into the tomcat directory and changing the log level in `logging.propertie` from "FINE" to "INFO" to no avail. I even tried to copy the file into eclipse and appending `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/logging.properties} -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` but that didn't help either (and of course I cleaned tomcat many times).

Also, in web.xml the only place I have the word 'log' not in comment is

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>gph</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.flographit</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>log</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and my `log4j.xml` files are configured with either `INFO` or `WARNING`, not `DEBUG`.

How can I limit the log to `INFO` or `WARNING`, or even just disallow unnecessary classes to log?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat uses Juli logging framework, a mix of Java Util Logging and Apache Commons Logging. You can either set the level in the JRE, youre Eclipse is running with ([JRE_DIR]/lib/logging.properties), or you can define your own one, i.e. copy the former into the Tomcat directory and add this to the run configuration:

Eclipse: "Run" -> "Run Configurations" -> select Tomcat to the left -> select tab "Arguments" to the right -> add this to "VM Arguments":

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=[PATH_TO TOMCAT]\lib\logging.properties
```

In that file, change these lines:

```
.level=INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
```

Thats it.

Comment: No good. [JRE_DIR]/lib/logging.properties was already configured with 'INFO', so I did what you told me ('Run -> 'Run Configurations'...) and no good came of it either,